# I want to sort this list of email address

Tags: python

So I am trying to sort a list of emails to see how many are sent by each email but I keep getting:

```
    filename = input("Enter File Name ")
file = open(filename)
lst = list()
for line in file :
    if line.startswith('From: '):
        y = line.split('From: ')[1]
        y.sort()
        print(y)
```

----> 7         y.sort()

```
      8        print(y)
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: You're currently not using your list. Try appending to it `lst.append(y)` and doing a sort on it after the loop

Answer (score 5):

You need to append each line to your list, then sort the list. `y.sort()` is trying to sort an individual line; the error happens because `y` is a string, and they don't have a `sort()` method.

```py
filename = input("Enter File Name ")
file = open(filename)
lst = list()

for line in file:
    if line.startswith('From: '):
        lst.append(line.split('From: ')[1])

lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: Or: `print(sorted(line.split('From: ')[1] for line in file if line.startswith('From: ')))`

Comment: Yes, a generator expression could work, but there needs to be a balance between writing nifty compact code and making things harder to read/follow. In this case, I think the generator expression hinders readability and might not be something the OP is familiar with. If one doesn't know about generators and the fact their contents are consumed as soon as they're accessed, they can cause new problems.